# FORCE limit the value of a column

Tags: javascript

How do you force a limit total?  Is this correct syntax? or am I missing something cause it's exceeding total number from my calculation.

```
 switch (ddlVal) {

case RequestTypes["Sick"]:
case RequestTypes["Late"]:
case RequestTypes["Jury Duty"]:
    tbEffectiveDate.disabled = false;
    ddlTotalHoursEffect.disabled = true;
    tbFromDate.disabled = true;
    tbToDate.disabled = true;
    cb.disabled = true;
    cb.checked = false;
    approvalRequired = false;
    commentsRequired = false;
    $("#spnDayOff").hide();
    break;

case RequestTypes["Day Off"]:
    tbEffectiveDate.disabled = false;
    ddlTotalHoursEffect.disabled = true;
    TotalHoursEffect <= 241  //THIS IS THE PART I WANT TO LIMIT DATA.
    tbFromDate.disabled = true;
    $("#spnDayOff").show();
    break;
default:
    break;
```

Comment: What's the subject? What's the language and Framework version? In general, what are you talking about?

Comment: What is the surrounding code?  That snippet alone is just a boolean statement, which will return true or false.  It doesn't manipulate the data or anything.

Comment: I know and that's the part I don't know.  I just want to limit data on a TOTALCOLUMN on xxx number.

Comment: How to limit the ammount of data entered in a particular column?  is that help

Comment: Really, you will need to supply more information. Where does totalcolumn come into the picture? Is it a property of some control. If so, what kind of control. Please edit the question and add this info, and preferably some code showing where you don't get the result that you want.

Comment: case RequestTypes["Day Off"]:
tbEffectiveDate.disabled = false;
ddlTotalHoursEffect.disabled = true;
ddlTotalHoursEffect.disabled <= 241  //THIS IS THE LOGIC I WANT.
break;

Comment: What language is this? It looks like there is some jQuery going on? JavaScript? Please, read your question and imagine you have never seen the software you are writing. Is there enough information to understand the problem? If not, keep adding information until no extra knowledge is required to understand the problem. People are here to help out by answering questions, not to spend time trying to guess what the question is.

Comment: @Yonita: I still have no idea what you're talking about. Please consider writing it down in the language you normally speak, in enough detail for a stranger to understand you. Then get it translated into English. As it stands, I doubt that anyone understands well enough to help you.

Comment: Mystery questions. My favorite!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first, this is not c#. Please retag this item as javascript and jQuery as that's what it appears to be.

So what exactly are you trying to accomplish here?
The subject says "FORCE limit data". What does that mean?

Lemme take a wild guess
case RequestTypes["Day Off"]: <~~~ some control was acted upon and "Day Off" was chosen, now you want to disable a dropdown??? 
tbEffectiveDate.disabled = false;
ddlTotalHoursEffect.disabled = true;

I don't believe these are true/false. I think "" is enabled and "disabled" is disabled.
Then you have "ddlTotalHoursEffect <= 241 "
If a drop down list is less than or equal 241???? I think (if ur using jQuery) you would set a variable equal to the integer value of the dropdown.

var totalHoursEffect = parseInt(ddlTotalHoursEffect.val());

then you can compare that to the 241?
if totalHoursEffect <= 241 dosomething()

Thats about as far as I can go with this.
Looks to me like you really want validation. You need to write some kind of function or set a variable to inspect later

Like this
var thisIsValid  = (totalHoursEffect <= 241)? true: false;

Then you would inspect thisIsValid  to see if the user can continue.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to disable the tbFromDate if `TotalHoursEffect <= 241`?

```
// Force the TotalHoursEffect to be limited to 241
if (TotalHoursEffect > 241) {  //THIS IS THE PART I WANT TO LIMIT DATA.
    TotalHoursEffect = 241;
}
```

Comment: yes, and that's ok.  I just need the TotalHoursEffect column to be limit or less than 241 value.

Comment: can i mix CASE statement and IF statement within?  I've never done that but is that possible?

Comment: Yes, it is. Just make sure you have: "if(...){ ... }". Keep the { and } matched.